# Stacked with this Problem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

I have been struggling for quite some time with the following problem and I would really appreciate some help: Consider $f(d)=\frac{(1-d)\left(1-d^{(\frac{t}{2}-1)}\right)}{(1-d)\left(1-d^{(\frac{t}{2}-1)}\right)+\left(1-d^{(\frac{s}{4})}\right)^2}$, where $t$ and $s$ are both multiples of 4 and $d \in [0,1)$. I conjecture and trying to show that this function is either always decreasing (if $s>t$), or it is initially decreasing and then increasing (if $t>s$). Up to now I have managed to show the case where $t>s$ and the first case only if $s/2>t$.

I am afraid of missing something obvious, but it's getting a bit frustrating. Any help would be more than welcome. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note: *not a full answer*, but something which may lend a hand:

Let $t=4m,\ s=4n,\ x=d,$ and define 
$$g(m,x)=(1-x)(1-x^{2m-1}),\quad h(n,x)=(1-x^n)^2.$$
Then your function is 
$$f(x)=\frac{g(m,x)}{g(m,x)+h(n,x)}=\frac{1}{1+h(n,x)/g(n,x)}.$$
Then $f(x)$ will increase or decrease iff $h/g$ respectively decreases or increases, so to keep things easier we can work instead with $g/h$ which will then increase or decrease with $f.$

To get at the derivative of $g/h$ we first factor out the copies of $(1-x)$ and arrive at
$$(g/h)(x)=\frac{1+x+\cdots+x^{2m-2}}{(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})^2}.$$
We now apply the quotient rule, ignoring the squared denominator and the extra factor coming from the fact that the denominator of $g/h$ is already squared (i.e. we factor one of those out). We arrive at the following expression, which has the same sign as the derivative of $g/h$ [and so the same sign as $f'$

$$(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})(1+2x+3x^2+ \cdots+(2m-2)x^{2m-3}) \\
-2(1+x+\cdots+x^{2m-2})(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+(n-1)x^{n-2}).\tag{1}$$

We get right away that at $x=0$ we have $f'<0$ in any case. The derivative is hard to work with otherwise, but at least we can see what is happening at $x=1$, by substituting $1$ for $x$ in the expression $(1)$ and using the formula for the sum of the first $k$ integers twice, and otherwise keeping track of the numbers of terms added. When this is done, we get that expression $(1)$ evaluated at $x=1$ has the value $(m-n)(2m-1)n$. That is, when $m=n$ we find $f$ is horizontal at $1$, when $m>n$ $f$ is increasing at $1$ (in agreement with the part of the question OP said was solved) and when $m<n$ we have $f$ decreasing at $1$.

Of course this is not a complete answer, since $f$ might be decreasing at both $0$ and $1$ but not on the whole interval $[0,1).$ Perhaps one might show any $f$ is concave up, which seems so experimentally.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply.

I am stacked exactly at the same point, although I was working out the derivative of the initial function. Trying to evaluate the behavior of this expression between 0 and 1 does not seem easy at all.

...(continues)

Comment: Even for the two cases that I have managed to show it, it was not by this way. It was by using Descartes' rule of signs in the following way.

First, notice that, as you pointed out, we can eliminate $(1-x)^2$ from numerator and denominator and construct a new function that is also well defined at 1. This is the function we use. namely, $f(x)=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m-2}x^k}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m-2}x^k+\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k \right)^2}$

...(continues)

Comment: We can see that the function takes values in (0,1). Then we can find how many solutions has the expression $f(x)=c$ for each $c \in (0,1)$. We need to differentiate between $c\geq 1/2$ and $c <1/2$ and we get that for $t>s$ this has at most two roots in $\mathbb{R}_+$ and given that $f'(0)<0$ and $f'(1)>0$ it means that  both of them are in (0,1). Therefore, it is first decreasing and then increasing.

Comment: On the other hand, is $t<s/2$ then for $c\geq 1/2$ this has no roots and for $c<1/2$ it has one root in $\mathbb{R}_+$, hence it has at most one root in $(0,1)$. Again, given that $f'(0)<0$ the function is decreasing. 

The problem is that for $s/2<t<s$ and $c<1/2$ this method gives that the function has either one or three roots in $\mathbb{R}_+$. In fact numerically, I see that this is decreasing until 1, but afterwards in some cases it starts increasing and then decreasing again. But I never see this happening before $x=1$.

I have tried several things more, but unsuccessfully so far.

Comment: Thank you once again for your time and effort...